# Space on top of second div using display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am facing a weird issue while using display: inline-block on 2 elements.

Maybe I am missing something but why there is some space on top of the button ?

Code here:

```css
.contact-validation {
  text-align: right;
}

.contact-captcha {
  width: 320px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #879;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact-submit {
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact-button {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-validation">
  <div class="contact-captcha"></div>
  <div class="contact-submit">
    <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Get in Touch</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Issue here: http://jsbin.com/jowosejahe/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply the Vertical-align :

```css
.contact-validation {  
  text-align: right;
}

.contact-captcha {
  width: 35%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color:#879;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact-submit {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.contact-button {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-validation">
    <div class="contact-captcha"></div>
    <div class="contact-submit">
        <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Get in Touch</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: answer is so fast that I can't accept it yet lol. Any ideas what this isn't by default ?

Answer (score 0):

i have change same css and remove  you can replace two class

```
.contact-validation {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; 
 }

.contact-captcha {
    width: 320px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #879;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in my computer and I can see like there is something strange on the space between the two divs:

```
<div class="contact-captcha"></div>
<div class="contact-submit">
  <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Get in Touch</button>
</div>
```

If you erase the newline between the divs:

```
<div class="contact-captcha"></div><div class="contact-submit">
  <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Get in Touch</button>
</div>
```

The space between them disappears. I think is because of the properties of the inline-block, that takes each character into his code as something to be written. Also if you end your first div like this:

```
<div class="contact-captcha"/>
<div class="contact-submit">
  <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Get in Touch</button>
</div>
```

It works different too. Maybe you want this to happen instead. Hope it helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Change these two elements to contain float:right.

```
.contact-captcha {
  width: 320px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color:#879;
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}

.contact-submit {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```